# How to see whether the `stripe-pricing-table` script is in a loading state? (React)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm integrating a `stripe-pricing-table` into a React web application and, because it's an iFrame, it takes a moment to load.

Stripe has it set up like this for React projects:

1. Add a `<script async ...>` tag to the `<Head>` component of the App (in my case, `<Head>` is exported from `next/document` because this is a Next.js project.
2. Bring `<stripe-pricing-table ...>` into the React component in line.

I've checked [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table#embed) and there isn't any mention of anything like this.

### Expected Behavior

There would be some way to expose whether the async fcn of loading the script is in a loading state, which would enable us to more elegantly handle the load on the front-end rather than just a flash on the screen when the iFrame is loaded.

### Observed Behavior

Currently, I can't find any way to expose a loading / async state related to this script / iFrame, so the page just has a white box that flashes on the screen when it's loaded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a feature request, maybe you should contact Stripe Support (https://support.stripe.com/contact) directly and ask for adding some event/callback to the <stripe-pricing-table> element.